# Run TypeScript file and get the result in .NET Core

Tags: c#, typescript, .net-core

I'm trying to use typescript as a template to create a json object.

Here is my .net core controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetJson(string key)
{
    object data = GetDataFromDataSource(key);
    var jsonContent = RunTypeScriptFileAndBindData($"{key}.ts", data);

    return Ok(jsonContent);
}
```

So how could I run typescript file in .net core and get the result?

All of my `.ts` files have to implement this interface:

```
interface expectation {

    getTemplate(): contract[];
}
```

any idea?

Comment: This sounds like a strange requirement. Maybe you are really looking for something like https://jsonnet.org/

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I may understand if you suggested https://www.stringtemplate.org/ but I'm not sure how https://jsonnet.org/ will help?

Comment: You want to create JSON from a template. That's what Jsonnet does.